# Multiple bind_rows with R Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, bind

I need to bind_row 27 excel files. Although I can do it manually, I want to do it with a loop. The problem with the loop is that it will bind the first file to `i` and then the first file to `i+1`, hence losing `i`. How can I fix this?

```
nm <- list.files(path="sample/sample/sample/")

df <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:27){
  my_data <- bind_rows(df, read_excel(path = nm[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could loop over the files with `map`, read the data with `read_excel` and rbind with `_dfr`

```
library(purrr)
my_data <- map_dfr(nm, read_excel)
```

---

In the Op's code, the issue is that in each iteration, it is creating a temporary dataset 'my_data', instead, it should be binded to the original 'df' already created

```
for(i in 1:27){
  df <- rbind(df, read_excel(path = nm[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We could use `sapply`

```
result <- sapply(files, read_excel, simplify=FALSE) %>% 
    bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

Comment: Congrats brother on reaching 10k reps for your contributions.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use your for loop:

```
my_data<-vector('list', 27)
for(i in 1:27){
  my_data[i] <- read_excel(path = nm[i])
}
do.call(rbind, my_data)
```